# use django create database scheme or use powerdesigner create database scheme

Tags: python, django, database, powerdesigner

I am ready to start a new project with django,and it invloves some operations with database.I have 2 way to get the scheme:

1. use powerdesigner design the database scheme and output sql,then use `python manage.py inspectdb` to generate models.
2. design the model then use `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to get the database scheme.

Does someone explain what this 2 ways' difference are and how should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [inspectdb's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) documentation:

> Use this if you have a legacy database with which you’d like to use
>   Django. The script will inspect the database and create a model for
>   each table within it.

Its better if you already have a working DB and want to use django on it. It has limitations like:

> 1. If inspectdb cannot map a column’s type to a model field type, it’ll use TextField and will insert the Python comment 'This field
>      type is a guess.' next to the field in the generated model.
> 2. If the database column name is a Python reserved word (such as 'pass', 'class' or 'for'), inspectdb will append '_field' to the
>      attribute name. For example, if a table has a column 'for', the
>      generated model will have a field 'for_field', with the db_column
>      attribute set to 'for'. inspectdb will insert the Python comment
>      'Field renamed because it was a Python reserved word.' next to the
>      field.

Also its a shortcut method, not recommended for if you are starting django project.

Also writing models, running `makemigration` and `migrate` command will create database scheme containing custom fields such as :

```
auth_group                               
auth_group_permissions                   
auth_permission                          
auth_user                                
auth_user_groups                         
auth_user_user_permissions
```

Which are essential for django system if you want to use its [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/), User model etc which are core parts of django.